# DurandalJs ignore anchor with #

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, durandal-2.0

I'm trying to implement Zurb Foundation tabs in a DurandalJS app.  Zurb Foundation uses # in their tab HTML structure.  The # is used to link tab with it's contents.

```
<ul class="tabs" data-tab>
    <li class="tab-title active"><a href="#panel2-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel2-2">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs-content">
    <div class="content active" id="Div1">
        <p>First panel content goes here...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="Div2">
        <p>Second panel content goes here...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

DurandalJs is intercepting the anchor clicks and is loading my default page instead of allowing Zurb to change tabs.  How do I tell DurandalJs to ignore the anchors that are used in Zurb's tab structure?

Comment: This is more of a DurandalJs question.

Comment: Not true! This is a very common problem between single page application routers and tabs because they both customarily use anchortags in their routes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem in single page application routers and tabs because they both use anchortags in their urls. What I would recommend is to take a different approach on your tabs structure one that does not involve anchortags.